# How to add a cover/PDF in a existing iText document

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need some help with iText. I need to add an existing pdf cover in other existing iText document or PDF document. Anybody could help me?
I've searched in some books (iText in action) but it's somewhat compicated.

Comment: Can you please describe what you have tried so far? As asked, your question is too broad and open-ended for Stack Overflow.

Comment: dgvid, What I needed was exactly what Bruno Lowagie answered. I needed to add a cover in my iText Document and later edit it. But thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we have a document named [pages.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/pages.pdf) and that we want to add the cover [hero.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hero_0.pdf) as the cover of this document.

**Approach 1:** Use `PdfCopy`

Take a look at the [AddCover1](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/AddCover1) example:

```
PdfReader cover = new PdfReader("hero.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("pages.pdf");
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("pages_with_cover.pdf"));
document.open();
copy.addDocument(cover);
copy.addDocument(reader);
document.close();
cover.close();
reader.close();
```

The result is a document where you first have the cover and then the rest of the document: [pages_with_cover.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/pages_with_cover.pdf)

**Approach 2:** Use `PdfStamper`

Take a look at the [AddCover2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/AddCover2) example:

```
PdfReader cover = new PdfReader("hero.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("pages.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("cover_with_pages.pdf"));
stamper.insertPage(1, cover.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
PdfContentByte page1 = stamper.getOverContent(1);
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(cover, 1);
page1.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
stamper.close();
cover.close();
reader.close();
```

In this case, we take the original document `pages.pdf` and we insert a new page 1 with the same page size as the cover. We then get this `page1` and we add the first page of `hero.pdf` to this first page. The result is [cover_with_pages.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/cover_with_pages.pdf)

**What is the difference between the two approaches?**

With `PdfCopy`, you may lose some of the properties that are defined at the document level (e.g. the page layout setting), but you keep the interactive features of both files. You may need to set some parameters in case you want to preserve tagging, form fields, etc... but for simple PDFs, you don't need all of that.

With `PdfStamper`, you preserve the properties that are defined at the document level of `pages.pdf`, but you lose all the interactive features of the cover page (if any). You may need to tweak the example if you want to define the cover as an artifact and if the original cover page has odd page boundaries, but it would lead us too far to discuss this in this simple answer.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie, I'm sorry for the comments about your books. I apologize.
Your answer was what I needed. Helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I've removed the comment from my answer. It is custom to accept answers that provide the information that you needed.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie, Thanks again with your help.
A last question,  do you know how to resize the imported PDF to fit on the PDF document? My "hero.pdf" is a little large than the "pages.pdf". I'll need to create another stack question to it?

Comment: This is already answered in other questions. The best way is to use approach 2 and to scale the `page` object. This can either be done by using a different `addTemplate()` method (with more parameters) or by wrapping the `page` object inside an `Image` and use `scaleToFit()` to fit the image inside a specific rectangle.